# Gamemaker Loop Question

Tags: game-loop, game-maker

How often do loops repeat in game maker? Is it every step, or as fast as it can handle? I need it to loop every step, is it possible to do that? I'm talking about in code, I have a do until loop. Just interested in the facts, here.

Comment: Can you provide more information about the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

The entire [loop](http://wiki.yoyogames.com/index.php/Loop) will process every time the script that contains it is called. This happens inside a single frame.

Comment: So every time a script (or D&D) that has the loop gets called, the loop will be executed until its finished. For example if you put the loop inside the "Create" event, it will get called once upon creation If you put it inside step, it will be called every frame (and you decide the framerate based on room_speed)